# Eclipse: Opening a view in detached window

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

Say I have a a detached window with a view in it. And I have an action to open the same kind of view, I would like to open it in the detached window, is there anyway to do it?

I have tried getting the IWorkBenchPage of the detached window where the open action is called and calling showView on it, but the new window is still opened in the Eclipse window.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done in Eclipse from version Mars(4.5) and higher Using the mars specific UI API. e.g. MPart as opposed to ViewPart